# pyspark dataframe inner join -package$TreeNodeException

Tags: python, pyspark, inner-join

I am doing an inner join between pyspark dataframe using id.

```
same_id=final_id.join(df_id, on="id", how="inner")

same_id.count()
```

Both final_id and df_id contains around 15M records.

But I keep getting this error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o484.count.
: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$TreeNodeException: execute, tree:
Exchange SinglePartition
+- *(2) HashAggregate(keys=[], functions=[partial_count(1)], output=[count#9086L])
   +- *(2) Project
      +- *(2) BroadcastHashJoin [_id#6701], [_id#548], Inner, BuildLeft
         :- BroadcastExchange
```

What else can I do to  fix the error? Is there a better way than inner join to find out the ids that exist in both final_id and df_id?

Comment: are you running above code is it in pyspark shell or some other ide?

Comment: @484 running it in Jupyter Notebook